# How To Find The BigQuery Table Required Columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in the BigQuery that I would like to know what fields are required. How do I do that?  Thanks in advance!

I tried the following queries, but none of them tell me the required field information.

```
SELECT * FROM mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM `myprojectid`.mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'mytablename'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `is_nullable` column:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, is_nullable
FROM `myprojectid`.mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'mytablename'
```